# How to pass a specific array element for a callback of event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects that holds each "actionButton" id, selector and callback

```
var actionButtons = [
    {
        id:"0",
        selector:"._55ln._qhr",
        callback: undefined
    },
    {
        id:"1",
        selector:"._22aq._jhr",
        callback: undefined
    },
    .
    .
    .
];
```

What I'm trying to do is calling a function with a specific parameter from the array(the id) every time a selector is clicked.

```
for(var i=0;i<actionButtons.length;i++){
    $(document).on('click', actionButtons[i].selector, function() {
        makeAction(actionButtons[i].id);
        if (actionButtons[i].callback)
            actionButtons[i].callback(this);
    });
}
```

But this code is not working; it looks like every time the callback function is called the value of `i` is equal to the array size.

How can I solve this problem;ie. to make the value of the variable `i` become different for each callback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because the `i` variable is being incremented in the loop. This means that when the first event handler actually runs after the loop completes, `i` is the maximum value, not `0`.

To fix this you can use a closure:

```
for(var i = 0; i < actionButtons.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    $(document).on('click', actionButtons[i].selector, function() {
      makeAction(actionButtons[i].id);
      if (actionButtons[i].callback)
        actionButtons[i].callback(this);
    });
  })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order not to fall into closure ambush you may always use array methods like

```
actionButtons.forEach(function(ab) {
  $(document).on('click', ab.selector, function() {
    makeAction(ab.id);
    ab.callback && ab.callback(this);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let):

> The let statement declares a block scope local variable, optionally initializing it to a value.

**Let** will assure you the closure.

```
for(let i=0;i<actionButtons.length;i++){
   $(document).on('click', actionButtons[i].selector, function() {
       makeAction(actionButtons[i].id);
       if (actionButtons[i].callback)
         actionButtons[i].callback(this);
     });
}
```